# Relationship types as variables

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want the relationship label to be "xxxyyy" the combination of the nodes,
 or even xxx_yyy, "+" is string concatenation or set up a variable as x = a.name + b.name but what I try or have looked up fails.

Appears no quotes or dollar sign in relationship label, could save me a lot of typing.

```
MATCH (a:book),(b:story)
WHERE a.Name = "xxx" AND b.Name = "yyy"
CREATE (a)-[r:a.name+b.name]->(b)
RETURN r
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of doing that, versus just using a constant relationship type (like CONTAINS)?

Comment: I have a very very large number of nodes and want the relationship name to be the concatenation of the  2 connected nodes, seems the easiest way to identify them,   I can cut and paste the same come and just change the 2 variables names for the nodes.  I do not see how contains would do this.

Comment: You can use `MATCH (a:book {name: 'xxx'})-[:CONTAINS]->(b:story {name: 'yyy'})` to find the path between the 2 books in your example. What you are trying to do is not the "natural" way to model the data and might be very inefficient, depending on what your code looks like.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible in plain Cypher, but you can use the [`apoc.create.relationship`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) procedure to accomplish this:

```
MATCH (a:book),(b:story) 
WHERE a.Name = "xxx" AND b.Name = "yyy" 
CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, a.name + b.name, {}, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say there are `S` story names, and on average every story has `B` book names. That would give you `S * B` relationship types. It is not good practice to create that many relationship types, especially when the type names incorporate actual data values. In fact, the lack of Cypher support for what you wanted to do is an indication that it is a bad practice.

A relationship type name should should indicate a "type of relationship" -- and not be so granular as to denote a "specific individual relationship". Instead, to find a specific relationship, you should use its type name, and its the property values and/or the property values of the nodes it connects.

Here are some examples of what you might want to do instead.

Create a `CONTAINS` relationship between a book and a story (for better performance, you should also create [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:book(Name)` and `:story(Name)`)):

```
MATCH (b:book),(s:story)
WHERE b.Name = "xxx" AND s.Name = "yyy"
CREATE (b)-[r:CONTAINS]->(s)
RETURN r;
```

To get all the books that contain a specific story:

```
MATCH (b:book)-[:CONTAINS]->(s:story)
WHERE s.Name = "yyy"
RETURN b;
```

To get all the stories contained in a specific book:

```
MATCH (b:book)-[:CONTAINS]->(s:story)
WHERE b.Name = "xxx"
RETURN s;
```

To verify that a specific book contains a specific story, and get them:

```
MATCH (b:book)-[:CONTAINS]->(s:story)
WHERE b.Name = "xxx" AND s.Name = "yyy"
RETURN b, s;
```

Comment: "the lack of Cypher support for what you wanted to do is an indication that it is a bad practice."
Agreed, which is why the question and your answer are so valuable. The solutions and best approaches in a graph model are distinct from pattern matching in a programming language. The flexibility of Neo4j's modelling is one of its strengths, and it means a modelling change like this is a perfectly valid, non-breaking (and possibly the best) solution.